# Adding small caps to my bibliography title

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I use `classic thesis` and I would like to have the title of my references in caps in the table of contents, but it is not the case. What do I have to do ? This is my preamble :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{../classicthesis} %   
...
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
...
{ \raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mabiblio}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to `apacite`'s redifiniton of `thebibliography` environment.  There are at least two approaches.

The first is if you are prepared to have the references as a numbered chapter, then essentially all you need to do is tell `apacite` that, and it will generated the heading with the standard `\chapter` command, which will generate the corresponding toc entry as for other chapters.

The second is if you want the references to be an unnumbered chapter, then you have to modify `apacite` interally to make it add a toc entry with desired formatting.  This has to be done in a way compatible with `hyerref`.

In both cases, there are some problems with your set-up.

- `apacite` needs to be loaded after `classicthesis`
- `hyperref` is also required

### Pictures

First approach:

[image: First sample]

Second approach:

[image: Second sample]

### Code

First approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\section{Test section}

\nocite{*}

{ \raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{xampl}}

\end{document}
```

Second approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\st@rtbibchapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}}{\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\bibname}}}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\section{Test section}

\nocite{*}

{ \raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{xampl}}

\end{document}
```

(`xampl.bib` is a bibfile contained in standard distributions, used for the documentation of `bibtex`)

Comment: It works fine ! Thanks so much for your help !